# Creating variables with identifiers from a character vector

Tags: r, rlang

Creating variables is easy:

```
`a b` <- 1
`c d` <- 2
```

or alternatively:

```
`<-`("a b", 1)
`<-`("c d", 2)
```

Here, I have a vector of the variable names `x <- c("a b", "c d")`, but I'm trying to assign `1` to `` `a b` `` with

```
`<-`(x[1], 1)
```

but this translates to `x[1] <- 1` rather than `` `a b` <- 1 ``.

I tried

```
`<-`(get(x[1]), 1)
```

and

```
library(rlang)
`<-`(expr(!!x[1]), 1)
```

but none of these works. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't get into the habit of creating symbols that are not valid syntax.

Comment: Could you please clarify which symbols are not valid?

Comment: All symbols that need to be quoted, e.g., symbols containing a space character.

Comment: Yes, symbols with spaces are non-standard but I wouldn't say they are invalid (otherwise they won't run). I'm using this to get the tooltips of my `plotly` to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `assign` :

```
assign(x[1], 1)
`a b`
#[1] 1
```